# Using Serial input together with SPI

Tags: c++, arm, stm32, uart, spi

I am working on a project where I am receiving serial data on UART6_RX.
This works perfectly fine.

However, when I add a touchscreen button to the screen and in the main while loop check if it is touched, the UART_RX doesn't receive any data anymore. I've got the feeling that it has something to do with interrupts.

I currently have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    device.baud(31250);  
    lcd.Clear(BACK_COLOR);

    Button firstButton(lcd, ts, 10, Y0, btnWidth, btnHeight,LCD_COLOR_RED, BACK_COLOR, "My First Button", Font24);

    while(1) {  

        if (firstButton.Touched()) //If I remove this if statement, everything works perfectly. 
        {
            int n = 10; 
        }      
       // __disable_irq(); //Tried this, but without succes

        if (device.readable()) {
            char cReceivedByte = device.getc();
            unsigned long result= doSomethingAmazing(cOntvangenByte);
            char buf[10];
            sprintf(buf, "%05lu\r\n", result);

            lcd.SetBackColor(LCD_COLOR_GREEN);
            lcd.SetTextColor(LCD_COLOR_WHITE);
            lcd.SetFont(&Font24);
            lcd.DisplayStringAt(270, LINE(5), (uint8_t *)buf, LEFT_MODE);
        }
      //  __enable_irq();
    }
}
```

I using the ARM - mbed compiler and am running it on the following dev board:
- STM32F7-Discovery

Who knows what is going on and how I can solve it?

Thanks a million times,

Alex

Comment: how this "touched" thing defined?

Comment: BTW, this button constructor hints that it is not C we are talking about...

Comment: thanks @EugeneSh. I should've been C++, my bad! This "touched thing" is defined in an external library. It reads (over SPI) the interrupt state of the touch controller.

Comment: So it might "externally" break something. You should look at it's implementation.

Comment: One possibility is that the button code and the display code are both trying to use the same pin, but for different purposes. Another possibility is an interrupt conflict. And then there's a million other possibilities.

Comment: This is very likely no C code. Use the correct tags. After 4 years you should know (and also how to edit a question).

Comment: Use a debugger and a scope/logic analyser.